# Web API Authentication with HttpModule

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building a WebApi application which needs to authenticate for every request by validating credentials from the HTTP header sent.

I was hoping to use an HttpModule for this, but when I debug, the module is only hit when I start the app. I can actively fire requests at a controller action and it will never hit the HttpModule (and thus never check credentials).

I've activated the HttpModule in the web.config like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="MyAssembly.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule"/>
    </modules>
```

Why does the module not run when I call the controller - is this method not appropriate for authenticated WebApi apps? I can't use IIS authentication in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to ensure every single incoming Http request has the appropriate BasicAuth headers, try adding the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests attribute to the module in your config file:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule" type="MyAssembly.Modules.BasicAuthHttpModule"/>
</modules>
```

A more appropriate solution would be to use an Action Filter for authorization:

http://www.ryadel.com/en/http-basic-authentication-asp-net-mvc-using-custom-actionfilter/